# Facebook Connect error code 191, "Can't Load URL"

Tags: facebook

I've looked and tried so many things but unfortunately I have been unsuccessful in fixing the Facebook Connect on my forum (IP.Board 3.4). It worked before but for some unknown reason stopped working. Now I get an error (code 191)... I'm pretty sure I've got everything set up properly.

Here is the full error message being displayed when someone tries to register using FB:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "G9FSrFXlu0Y"
   }
}
```

**Screen 1**
[image: Screen1]

**Screen 2**
[image: Screen2]

Comment: For login via the website platform, you need to add an according Valid OAuth Redirect URI. (Because in that case, the address will not be apps.facebook.com/something)

Comment: Hi CBroe, thank you I changed it the https://fragnet.ca/forums but I'm still getting the 191 error... "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

Comment: The Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field must contain the exact value of the redirect_uri parameter in your login dialog call.

Comment: Thank you CBroe all good now!

Comment: Ok, I added the contents of the comments as a short answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you CBroe! I'm new to Stackoverflow been lurking for ever. This is my first post. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For login via the website platform, you need to add an according Valid OAuth Redirect URI. (Because in that case, the address will not be `apps.facebook.com/something`)

The Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field must contain the exact value of the redirect_uri parameter in your login dialog call.